# highcharts-angular dynamically update from DB

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using highcharts-angular in angular 6 app.
When I set data, hardcore it, in ngOnInit, chart is visible and works correctly.

But I want to update chart series dynamically, meaning add point to the series, add new series...
This will be done after calling web API and getting new data, calling loadBidChartData().

If I set new series for chat, or update series, chart don't see changes, initial state is not changing.
 **How can I solve this?**

Here is small peace of example code
in html is like this:

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block; overflow: auto;" [update]="true" ></highcharts-chart>
```

in angular:

```
 import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
 export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  Highcharts = Highcharts; // required    
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: "scatter",
        width: 900           
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 0,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.y + ' €';
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',            
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'number',            
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        floating: false,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    series: []      
};

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions.series= [{
            name: 'first last',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 25), 23], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 57, 15), 132], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 2), 312], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 15), 432]]
        }];
}

loadBidChartData(bidApiModel: BidItem[]): void {
    this.chartOptions.series= [{
        name: 'first last',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 25), 23], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 57, 15), 132], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 2), 312], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 15), 432]]
    },
    {
        name: 'second last',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 28), 50], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 45), 152], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 53), 250], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 57, 11), 320]]
    }];
 }
}
```

**Solution**:
Working demo with updating in background and adding and removing points to highcharts: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bv26xz 
Thank you **User3250** and **Wojciech Chmiel** for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[(update)]` flag to update the series as below:

```
loadBidChartData(bidApiModel: BidItem[]): void {
    this.chartOptions.series= [{
        name: 'first last',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 25), 23], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 57, 15), 132], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 2), 312], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 58, 15), 432]]
    },
    {
        name: 'second last',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 28), 50], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 45), 152], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 56, 53), 250], [Date.UTC(2018, 11, 16, 10, 57, 11), 320]]
    }];
   this.updateFlag = true;
}

<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block; overflow: auto;" [(update)]="updateFlag" ></highcharts-chart>
```

Working demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5spve

Comment: Check also this demo with an update: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4